# How to print an array of int by blocks of numbers? (Histogram printing)

Tags: c, arrays, histogram

For this program, I'm meant to generate a certain number of random ints with a given range. For example 100 ints between 0-10.

I have created an array of distribution (called distTab) which shows how many times a certain number was generated. I then print the numbers as stars in a for loop. check the image below.

[image]

This works well for 0-10 but say I generate 10000 numbers between 0-1000 my print function prints every index of distTab. I would like to cut it by range and add index values to each other in that range. For example between 0-100 -> 20 stars, 101-200 -> 21 stars and so on.

Here's my code for printing the histogram currently:

```
int inc=0;

printf("\n%s\t%s\n","Number", "Histogram\n");
for(int i=0; i <= max; i++) {
    if(distTab[i]==0)       
        continue;

    printf("  %d\t",i);
    int lim = distTab[i];

    for(int j=1; j<=lim; j++){          
        printf("*");
        inc++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The random numbers and distTab are created like this (in a for loop):

```
int distTab[MAX_RAND];
memset(distTab, 0, sizeof distTab);

//for(0 -> desired number of ints)
    rnd = (rand() % limit)+1;
    if (max < rnd)
        max = rnd;  //max value generated.
    distTab[(int)rnd]++;
//}
```

Thanks in advance for your time and I hope I explained my question as clearly as I could.

Comment: Whatd have you tried ?

Comment: You need to write a function `int myfunc(int value)` (I let you find a more  suitable function name) that returns 20 if  `value` is between 0 and 100, 21 if the `value` is between 101 and 200, 22 for `value` between 201 and 300 etc. **Hint**: start with a pencil and a piece of paper.

Answer (score 0):

Scale the histogram. Or even better print it in percentage.
I would do something like

```
lim = distTab[i] / max_distTab * max_lim;
```

That way your most frequent value always has the same with.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it for numbers between 0 and 9999 and ranges of 100:

```
int inc=0;
int count[10] = {0};
printf("\n%s\t%s\n","Number", "Histogram\n");
for(int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
    if(distTab[i]==0)       
        continue;

    count[max % 100] += distTab[i];
 }

 for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    printf("%4d-%4d\t",i * 100, (i + 1) * 100);
    int lim = count[i];

    for(int j=1; j<=lim; j++){          
        printf("*");
        inc++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I used hard values to avoid variable lenght array however a better practice would be to either malloc your array or to use a define.

If you want a custom range you could also use another array of sorted int:

```
int ranges[] = {100, 300, 450, 600, 1000};
// assuming ranges is sorted
int get_index(int value, int* ranges){
  int count = 0;
  if (value > ranges[ranges.size() - 1])
    return -1;
  while (value < ranges[count])
    ++count;
  return count;
}
```

and replace

```
for(int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
    if(distTab[i]==0)       
        continue;

    count[max % 100] += distTab[i];
 }
```

By :

```
for(int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
    if(distTab[i]==0)       
        continue;

    count[get_index(i, ranges)] += distTab[i];
 }
```

Comment: Thanks ! I'm currently implementing your suggestions to my code. Will keep you posted if it works. It doesn't seem too difficult but I just cant wrap my head around it.

Comment: Which part would you like me to clarify ?